# Can HTML anchor tags ever be used for internal links in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, gatsby, anchor, preloading

I'm developing a website where a Search box can return a lot of results in a dropdown list and each result has a clickable internal link to a webpage within the same site.

I initially followed [Gatsby's advice](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/linking-between-pages/) and implemented these as `<Link>` elements, . However, this seems to be causing an issue when scrolling in the search results shortly after performing a new search - the scrollbar jumps back to the top of its own accord 3 or 4 times before then settling down afterwards. This is repeatable for the same search only after clearing the browser cache, which makes me suspect it is somehow related to Gatsby's pre-loading of pages.

If the links are changed to be HTML `<a>` tags instead, the problem goes away... but am concerned that this is going against Gatsby's advice and there may be other issues I don't know about yet (haven't seen anything so far...)

Could anyone advise whether it is advisable to use anchor tags for internal links in these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can always use the standard `<a>` tag for internal routing, however, you will be outside of React's scope (`@reach/router`'s scope). In your case, since you are not creating internal navigation *per se* (meaning navigation through internal pages) I think that your workaround is the lightest and most native approach, without adding extra dependencies which will increase the bundle size, with a functionality that can be handled natively.

As you said, `<Link>` component is compiled into an `<a>` tag with some React's vitamins in the end so, to me, it's the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

### Gatsby `<Link>` Issue When Using Tailwind Elements [offCanvas](https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/offcanvas/)

I had a similar issue using Gatsby `<Link>` inside an **offCanvas** component causing the page scroll to completly freezeon all devices untill navigating away. Guess the element using an event that conflicts with how the  triggers.
Replacing all `<Link>` tags that go to internal pages inside the component solve the problem. Refering to 'Ferren' answer, eventually  tags with `to` attributes compiled into  tags with `href`.

```
<div className={'offcanvas'} id={id} aria-labelledby={`#${id}Label`} tabIndex={-1}>
    <div className={'offcanvas-header'}>
      <a href={'/about'} className={'offcanvas-title'} id={'#offfcanvasLabel'}>
        About Us
      </a>
      <button type={'button'} data-bs-dismiss={'offcanvas'} aria-label={'Close'} tabIndex={-1}></button>
    </div>
...
```